# Debug Android mobile apps on an Android tablet

Tags: android, debugging, mobile, tablet

I 'd like to know if is it possible to debug Android mobile apps on an Android tablet, but not in full screen - in real size in the middle of the screen as does iPad with iPhone application.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your layout settings of the screens inside the app. If the width & height properties of the parent layout(layout with the xmlns attribute) is set to 'match_parent'/fill_parent', the application will occupy the entire screen in the tablet also. If you don't want the full screen set it into 'wrap_content'.